# Heroku rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, heroku, rake

when I run heroku rake db:migrate I keep getting:

```
Migrating to CreateUsers (20110216103237)
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
```

even though the Users table has already been created before. does anyone know why this might be occurring?

thanks

Comment: did you use the right environment? RAILS_ENV=production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have changed the database name in the database.yml file or you may have accidently deleted the last entry in schema_migrations table. Or maybe you did a `rake db:rollback`.

Comment: thanks for your response. I made no changes to the .yml file or to the schema. do you know if heroku creates all the tables in the schema every time I go a push to heroku? thanks.

Comment: no, db migrations have to be performed manually via the heroku rake command. Thing to do would be to look in the schema_migrations table to see if the migration ID is in there or not, if it's not then the migration would run if you ran a heroku rake db:migrate command